# Couch DB on MacOSX

Tags: couchdb

I followed the homebrew install guide here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX

It seems the process is running, but I can't access http://127.0.0.1:5984. Also, if I try and run sudo couchdb in terminal, it just hangs and nothing happens.

Is there an error log or something I can read to see whats up? I don't want to use the binary version.

Comment: Would you please run `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5984/` and paste the output into your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use CouchDbX:
http://janl.github.com/couchdbx/